# How To Prevent from overwriting data in database

Tags: java, database, jsf, locking

In my project multiple users have tasks to do where the user will be able to accept different types of files where in my code we will get the type of it then increment the value in table then save it .But due to high load some users accept at the same time so when the value should increment by 2 or 3 it only increment by 1 is there a way to increment the right value without needing to get the value then incrementing where this is causing wrong data. I am using jsf with hibrante and the database is oracle.

Comment: For example if the the user accept a file lets say 'A' in the database we will increment the coulmn called countA for example but due to accepting many requests at same time the value isn't reflecting the right count

Comment: Add clarifications as edits to the Question, not as Comments.

Comment: Your Question is not clear and specific. Look around at the Help pages and existing posts to learn how to write a better Question. Tip: “Concurrency” may be a helpful word to search.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.